# memory leaks при использовании pop_back()

Tags: c++, stl

Для удаления последнего элемента в векторе использую `pop_back()`

```
void Parser::pop() {
    if (operand.size() < 1) 
        throw ParserException("stack is empty:(");
    else {
        operand.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Если после использования `pop_back()` я буду добавлять новый элемент в вектор с помощью `push_back()` будет утечка памяти, из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Так вы спрашиваете, будет ли утечка, или утверждаете, что она будет?

Comment: @Harry будет утечка памяти, утверждение

Comment: У стандартного `std::vector`? простите, не верю. Так сказать, доказательства в студию :)

Comment: @Harry У меня работает цикл в котором я определяю что нужно сделать (добавить, удалить и т.д) 
Если нужно добавить я использую такой прием 
 IOperand const *a;
 a = _factory.createOperand(return_type(iter->type),iter->value);
 operand.push_back(a);

и все хорошо работает, и pop_back удаляет в конце списка но если я после этого еще раз использую этот прием будет лик

Comment: Как вы определяете что есть леак?

Comment: @Harry system("leaks -q avm"); в конце выполнения программы

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы создаете нечто в динамической памяти, передаете указатель в вектор, а потом, когда он не нужен, просто его оттуда убираете? Или перед этим все же вызываете для него `delete`?

Comment: @Harry Нет. В этом и была проблема( спасибо)